# Problem with alpha blending in XNA

Tags: xna

Hi
i have a background and two png sprites
I want to make [this effect](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4152145/xnatesting4.jpg) using the provided background and sprites using XNA 3.1
I'm doing something wrong because i only get [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4152145/xnatesting5.jpg) As you noticed its not the effect i wanna do
It is possible do this effect with a few lines of code using alpha blending in XNA 3.1? A practical example would be really great!

Answer (score 1):

First, render textures that contain the shapes that you want to be transparent to texture A.
The textures containing the shapes should contain black shapes, on a transparent background -- easily constructed with image editing software like Photoshop.

Then take texture A and draw it over top of your scene using an effect (an HLSL shader) that does:

```
output = float4(0, 0, 0, A.r);
```

Effectively making the output image's alpha lower where A is darker.

The image will have clear portions where you drew your shapes on A, and will be black everywhere else.

Here are the details of the shader code:

```
sampler TextureSampler : register(s0);

float4 PS(float4 color : COLOR0, float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    float4 Color = tex2D(TextureSampler, texCoord); 

    Color = float4(0, 0, 0, Color.r);

    return Color;
}

technique Vicky
{
    pass P0
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 PS();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, i need to use Texture2D like [this](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4152145/xnatesting3preopaque.jpg) instead [this one](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4152145/xnatesting3pre.jpg)?

Comment: No, the shape should be black, on a white background. Just invert that white shape image. Technically you could use the first image you linked, but you would have to do `output.rgb = float4(0, 0, 0, 1-A.r);` in your shader instead.

Comment: Ok, so, is better use [inverted Texture2D](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4152145/xnatesting3preinvert.jpg) Actually i draw all the "light" shapes in a rendertarget. Is this ok?

Comment: And to be clear, you cant just draw the shapes on top of your scene. You have to draw them to a texture first, then draw that texture on top of your scene using a shader that makes the red channel the alpha channel, as per my answer.

Comment: No, that's still not okay. You want a fully opaque image with a black shape on a white background. Put [this image](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4152145/xnatesting3preopaque.jpg) into photoshop and invert it.

Comment: Here is the image that you want: http://i.imgur.com/Y17cR.png Now draw that as many times as you want onto a black screen-sized rendertarget, then draw that rendertarget on top of your scene using a shader that does what I wrote in the answer above.

Comment: Ok, im blind :) Just using your image i get full "black" screen using [this code](http://pastebin.com/YFdhtYmt)

Comment: Errr.. are you using XNA 3 instead of 4? How come?

Comment: You aren't using a shader to draw the render target. Also I don't remember how it goes in XNA 3, but I think your `spriteBatch.End();` call should be before you set the render target to null. Rendering to targets is much easier in XNA 4 by the way :)

Comment: sorry, it was my fault. now is render properly [code](http://pastebin.com/hqAUABb1) but now im having problems with the shader. Can you show me the pixel shader code?
I will promise you give all my karma points :)

Comment: You need to put `GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(0, null); sprCompose = maskRenderTarget.GetTexture();` after your spriteBatch.End() call because I think in XNA3 the default SB drawing is deferred, which means that the spritebatch doesn't really draw until the end call, so nothing is being drawn to your render target.

Comment: Oops, there was a small bug in my shader code. It's still untested, but should work.

Comment: Hmmm...using [this code](http://pastebin.com/2QRwws3q) and your Pixel Shader code i still have the "overlapping" problem as you can see in [this picture](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4152145/xnatest6.jpg) :(

Comment: Oops, that's my fault. Fortunately, we can fix this just by modifying your shape images! You need to make your shape images a black shape on a transparent background. Sorry about that :) No need to change any of your code though.

Comment: Hmmm...i make [this footage](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4152145/xnatest10.jpg) using some Texture2D involved in "lighting".(The Texture2D used for "circle light" is on the bottom-right corner) Maybe the error is in the SpriteBlendMode? 
Or with a minor changes in the pixel shader the overlapping error will be fixed?

Comment: @Vicky: Try setting your `SpriteBlendMode` to `Additive`

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution without shader.

You first need your fog of war textures to be black with the transparent parts as White.

1. Render your map and entity normally, to a RenderTarget2D
2. Clear your background to black
3. Start sprite batch with Additive blend
4. Render you fog of war textures
5. Start a new sprite batch with Multiply blend
6. Render your map RenderTarget2D on top of the whole screen